# Compare only Date of Datetime

Tags: c#, date, datetime

hi I have a case when i want to compare only date of datetime object. how can i achieve it without converting it to string.

```
public bool CheckSendEmailWithinCalendarDay(UnifiedUser user, string messageId, DateTime whenSent)
        {
            var result = _ctx.UserSpecificMessageHistories
                .Where(u => u.UserId == user.User.UserId)
                .Where(d => d.WhenSent.Date == whenSent.Date)
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.EmailTemplate.Id == messageId);

            return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
        }
```

Comment: You are comparing only `Date` here: `d.WhenSent.Date == whenSent.Date` isn't it working ok?

Comment: Is the data from Entity Framework?

Comment: how it's not working, what's wrong?

Comment: "it is not workin(g)" - are you getting any *error messages*? If so, what do they say?

Comment: no error, only breaks before continuing to return

Comment: without .Date it works

Answer (score 3):

You can use

[EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or, if you're up to date (EF 6)

[DbFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220143%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

As you seem to be in linq to entities.

Comment: The page you've linked to says "You cannot call this function directly". How do you use it exactly?

Comment: It just means you must be in a "linq to entities context". Usage : `d => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.WhenSent)` for example

Comment: @Chris Use it like this : `var result = _ctx.UserSpecificMessageHistories.Where(u => u.UserId == user.User.UserId).Where(d => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.WhenSent) == EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(whenSent)).FirstOrDefault(m => m.EmailTemplate.Id == messageId);`

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Corrected it.

Comment: I get warning that EntityFunctions.TruncateTime is obsolete and has been replaced by DataEntity.DbFunctions

Comment: Ah, I did wonder if it was that but I'd have still called what you did calling it directly but I guess actually its just going to be read and interpreted by the linq provider and translated and never really called...

Comment: @JohnDudley ok, mentioned this one also !

Comment: Hi solved the issue. I think it is not a quite good way, but anyway that works. var now = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.ToShortDateString()); Now I have only date here, so when call repository method I pass this value to store or check date.